# Bootstrap button padding makes it appear like the button is going past the container border

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Why does the "Subscribe now!" button go outside the container in the picture below and how can I make it so that the right edge lines up with the rest of the page? (column 12 in the bootstrap grid)

I have tried box-sizing: border-box but it had no effect.

My HTML code:

```css
.container-fluid {
  padding: 0;
}

.carousel-inner .carousel-item h1 {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 300%;
  /*-webkit-text-stroke:1px black;*/
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  /*text-align:right;*/
}

.carousel-inner .carousel-item img {
  filter: brightness(50%);
}

#paddingrow {
  padding: 25px;
}

#paddingrowLarge {
  padding: 100px;
}

#accordionRightalign {
  float: right;
}

#mycard {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row" id="paddingrow"></div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <h1 style="text-align:center">SUBSCRIBE TO OUR NEWSLETTER</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <form>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your email">
          </div>
          <button class="btn btn-primary" style="box-sizing: border-box" type="submit">Subscribe now!</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you post your custom css you have applied? with the code provided I cannot reproduce the issue

Comment: Added my css, though I think I fixed my issue:

"I noticed my button wasn't in the column div, so I ended up making two column div's, one size 10 and one size 2, put input in the first, put the button in the second, and it seems to work now."

I would still appreciate any general advice on my fix / my code in general.

Comment: I added the fixed version of the code in the original post.

Comment: I rolledback and removed your fix. Please add it as anwser and explain your fix and check it as solution.

Comment: Good to know, I added the code to my answer. There's a 2 day period before I can mark my comment as a solution, so I'll have to wait to do that.

Answer (score 2):

**Bootstrap rows** have `margin-right: -15px; margin-left: -15px;` that's why the right edge doesn't lined up. Try to add `mx-0` = `margin-left:0` and `margin-right: 0`, a bootstrap class. In your **nested row form**.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row" id="paddingrow"></div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <h1 style="text-align:center">SUBSCRIBE TO OUR NEWSLETTER</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <form>
        <div class="row mx-0">
          <div class="col pl-0 pr-3">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your email">
          </div>
          <button class="btn btn-primary" style="box-sizing: border-box" type="submit">Subscribe now!</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I noticed my button wasn't in the column div, I made two column div's, one size 10 and one size 2, put input in the first, put the button in the second, and it seems to work now.

But out of curiosity, how would I have implemented your suggestion? I actually noticed that detail as well, but making margin:0 made the form smaller than expected.

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. An anwser should be a 100% definite solution. You added an explanation of the issue but no solution. please add an actual solution and preferebly validate it with a working code snippet (**Ctrl + M**).

Comment: I explained further and added code snippet. @Clueless

Comment: Thanks, this made the button aligned on the right, but as a result the form is now slightly indented on the left. Here is an example: https://imgur.com/a/ihT6K9K.

I think the fix I commented is sufficient.

Comment: @Clueless Sorry for late reply, I think it is because of `col` inside of the row.

Comment: I edited the code for `col` I added `pl-0` and `pr-3` = `padding-left: 0` and `padding-right: 1rem;`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure col in the container with margin and padding to zero.
Put your image into container with the width not greather than 100%.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed my button wasn't in the column div, so I made two column div's, one size 10 and one size 2, put input in the first, put the button in the second, and it seems to work now.

Here is the fixed code:

```html
<div class="container">
           <div class="row" id="paddingrow"></div>
           <div class="row">
             <div class="col-sm-12">
               <h1 style="text-align:center">SUBSCRIBE TO OUR NEWSLETTER</h1>
             </div>
           </div>
           <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-12">
                <form class="form">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your email">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                      <button class="btn btn-primary w-100" type="submit">Subscribe now!</button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```